# Jquery plugin to allow only numbers in certain range in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for some jquery plugin that would allow only numbers from a certain range in a text input field.

It would be great if it worked similar to a datepicker. I.e. user clicks on a text field and a tiny window with some numbers from let's say 0 to 23 appears. User than just selects the number and clicks ok.

Before you start suggesting a select instead of text input field, I cannot use select in this case for certain reasons.

Comment: I guess if using another input method is not possible, using jquery's slider (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) is also impossible?

Comment: what are those certain reasons? graceful degradation? stone carved html? (pure curiosity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plugins/Validation/Methods/range](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/range) should get you started with making sure only a number in a certain range is entered.